# Using select multiple to send multiple values to google sheets using google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use multiple selector to post data to google sheet using google apps script as follows:

Code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form.html').evaluate()
.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

function doPost (e) {
var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
lock.tryLock(10 * 1000);
  
try {
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1
var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
return header === 'Timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
})
sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Confirmation.html').evaluate()
.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);

}

catch (e) {
return ContentService
.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
}

finally { lock.releaseLock() }

}
```

Form.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>

<form name="myForm" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwamMCkOCAmwrRDNj8cTqgp3cevm8B9niyrlYa5dnbxP2H3q0o/exec" target="_self" method="POST">

<div>
<select name="M Values" multiple required>
<option value="" disabled selected>Select Value(s)</option>
<option value="M1">M1</option>
<option value="M2">M2</option>
<option value="M3">M3</option>
<option value="M4">M4</option>
<option value="M5">M5</option>
<option value="M6">M6</option>
</select>
</div>
<button type="submit">Send</button>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is when a user chooses many options for example M1, M3, and M5 and click the submit button, I only receive M1 in the sheet instead of receiving all the selected values like that M1, M3, M5

Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FdOH2zU_ZnxB2a7RA_QfO3HdPTRhVhSHo5988a8Au9s/edit?usp=sharing

The sheet is editable so please feel free to use. Please any help is very appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: About `I tried to use e.postData.contents but it gives me the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'postData' of undefined`, in this case, `e` is `undefined`. So I'm worry that you might directly run the function of `doPost`. How about this? If my guess is not correct, can you provide the detail flow for replicating your issue of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'postData' of undefined`? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: "So I'm worry that you might directly run the function of doPost."
Yes I do, why wouldn't you recommend that?

"can you provide the detail flow for replicating your issue"
I just added the logger as indicated in the example code but I think I didn't understand the documentation in how to post an array of values in a single cell

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `"So I'm worry that you might directly run the function of doPost." Yes I do, why wouldn't you recommend that?`, the reason of your issue could be found. In your script, it seems that Web Apps is used. So please run the script with the Web Apps. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: Thank you for your interest and effort. I red the documentation and I have no problem in deploying the web app and receiving the inputs in the sheet. The problem is when I select many options from the multiple selector for example M2, M4, and M6 I only receive M2 in the sheet instead of receiving the full array like that M2, M4, M6

Comment: You can try from here https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwamMCkOCAmwrRDNj8cTqgp3cevm8B9niyrlYa5dnbxP2H3q0o/exec 
and see the results in Sheet1 in the spreadsheet shared in the question

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. In your current situation, your initial question of `I tried to use e.postData.contents but it gives me the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'postData' of undefined` was changed. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: May be I was unable to phrase the question in the first place. Now my form is working perfectly and I can receive the submitted inputs in the sheet except for one thing:
when I add a multiple selector to allow choosing many options, I only receive the first selected one so I red documentation in this part "e.postData.contents: The content text of the POST body like Alice,21" but I was not able to apply that in my code so when a user selects many options like I said for example M1, M2 and M3 and submit I receive the three submitted values in the cell instead of just M1

Comment: I updated the question to better explain the issue @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. I confirmed that your question had been changed. I'm glad your 1st question was resolved. About your new question, I proposed the modification points as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put all values of multi selected values to the cell.

I think that the reason of your new issue is due to `e.parameter[header]`. In this case, `e.parameter` is only one value in the selected values. So please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
return header === 'Timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
```

#### To:

```
return header === 'Timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameters[header].join(",");
```

#### Note:

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

#### Reference:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Comment: Tanaike, I don't know how to thank you for your effort and support.